# How do I speed up media scanning?

Tags: performance, media-search

When putting new music files or images onto the sd card of my android phone, android needs to scan for new files. Is there any way to speed up this process? E.g. putting all files in one directory? Currently I organized my music this way: `music/artists/albums/files.mp3` Any suggestions?

Comment: I also have this problem. I am using Musicolet player and there is an option to use Musicolet scanner or system scanner; also there is an option to choose which folders to scan. However scanning is slow. If I have huge audio files, scanning a single file can take minutes. So I wonder does the scanner have to scan each file byte by byte or what takes so long time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One method is to put a file called `.noMedia` in the root of every folder that you don't want to be scanned.  It won't improve the scanning of actual media, but it will prevent wasted time searching elsewhere (or indexing things that you don't want indexed, such as app assets).

Comment: Just a notice. It won't speed up scanning by a lot. Files with a `.nomedia` will still be **indexed**, but not **categorized**. You may wish to open Media Provider's database and see the table entries.

Answer (score 2):

some of the slowness may be due to the speed of your storage media.

If it's built in storage than there's not much you can do (apart from what Matthew Read suggested)

if it's an SD Card, maybe check that it's not a class 2 or something. perhaps try and get a class 10 to speed things up.

beyond those changes it's down to the device CPU speed

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to organize your files in any other theme. Android is indexing the media file and since api 1.0 player should query the Media Store which is using this index.

Comment: I guess you got me wrong. Building up the index is too slow, and I aimed on asking how it can be speed up.